# Using ROW_NUMBER in CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying for a CTE with a ROW_NUMBER function.

Query:

```
with Demo as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by GID, MID order by MMID) as ROWNUMBER  from Table1 where DateEntered > '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000'
)
select  * from Demo
```

Here, the result I get is

```
GID   MID   ROWNUMBER
1      1      1
1      2      1
1      2      2
1      2      3 
2      1      1
2      2      1
2      2      2
2      3      5
2      4      4
```

Now, I want to get all the rows where combination of GID,MID has max row number value. But a condition here is that for those rows, the combination of GID,MID should also have 1.

In simple terms, get me the rows with max row number value, if that combination of gid,mid has rownumber=1.

The output I desire is

```
GID   MID   ROWNUMBER
1      1      1
1      2      3 
2      1      1
2      2      2
```

I hope i did not made it complex. Can anyone pls inform me on how to do this ?

Comment: "get me the rows with **max row number value**, if that combination has **rownumber = 1**"?, how can that be unless every row number is 1?

Comment: @Lamak In the example given above, combination of GID,MID(e.g GID=1, MID =2) has ROWNUMBER's 1,2 3 . Here I want the row with ROWNUMBER = 3 .

Comment: `partition by GID, MID order by MID` is going to give arbitrary row numbers, since the ordering value will be the same for each member of the partition.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Order by MMID. It is different then MID.

Answer (score 2):

```
with Demo as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by GID, MID order by MMID) as RN  
from Table1 where DateEntered > '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000'
)
, x as 
(select gid, mid
from demo 
where RN = 1
)
select demo.gid, demo.mid, max(demo.rn) as rownumb
from demo left join x
on x.gid = demo.gid and x.mid = demo.mid
group by demo.gid, demo.mid;
```

You can use `max` to select the highest rownumber per mid, gid combination.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the row number value, just use `desc` instead of `asc` and a filter:

```
with Demo as (
     select t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by GID, MID order by MID DESC) as seqnum  
     from Table1
     where DateEntered > '2015-06-13'
    )
select  *
from Demo 
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you do want a more meaningful `ROWNUMBER` in the output, then use two calculations in the CTE.

Comment: I want the rows where seqnum is MAX, not =1

Comment: Use `desc` instead of `asc`, as I mention in the answer.  Then, the maximum value is given a row number of 1, the second largest 2, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
with Demo as
(
select *,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by GID, MID order by MMID) as ROWNUMBER  
from Table1 
where DateEntered > '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000'
)
select GID,
       MID,
       MAX(ROWNUMBER) as MaxROWNUMBER
from Demo
GROUP BY GID,MID;
```

Answer (score 1):

The max of `row_number()` is just count.

```
select GID, MID, COUNT(*) as ROWNUMBER
from Table1 
where DateEntered > '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000'
group by GID, MID
```

Comment: I want only those rows where ROWNUMBER is max and it has ROWNUMBER =1 also

Comment: How do you ever have a GID, MID pair without `ROW_NUMBER() = 1`. The first row will be 1.

Comment: When the rownumber has dateentered value less than '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000'. Then i will not have that row in my criteria. I hope i didnt confused you here.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` is assigned after the where clause eliminates rows, in you given query. The where clause will not eliminate `ROW_NUMBER()` = 1, unless all rows are eliminated, in which case there is no row to have a max on. Nor any rows included in my count.