# Not exist not working in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the 2nd bracket(two queries and their intersection), I get few rows which are different rows than the query '`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (DateEntered >= '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000')'`

But here, I get no result. I get 0 rows. Can you tell me where am i wrong, is it some syntax or some other thing ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE (DateEntered >= '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT GID, MID 
                  FROM Table1       
                  WHERE MMID IN (SELECT MAX(MMID) 
                                 FROM Table1
                                 WHERE DateEntered >= '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000'
                                 GROUP BY GID, MID)

intersect

SELECT GID, MID 
FROM Table1 
WHERE MMID IN (SELECT MIN(MMID) 
               FROM Table1
               WHERE DateEntered < '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000'
               GROUP BY GID, MID))
```

**Expected Output**

I want only those values, which are after 13 June and have never occurred before. So I intersect and get the values which are present before and after a date range. Then I remove it with Not exists.

Can you guide me on this ? Why am I getting 0 rows even though there should be some rows.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  "Not works" provides basically no information.

Comment: Sample data, and expected output would also be helpful.

Comment: First, you may want to start by marking your previous questions as answered before asking another question. This kind of behavior usually discourages other users to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054026/using-row-number-in-cte

Comment: How many rows are returned for `SELECT GID, MID FROM Table1        
        WHERE MMID IN (
            SELECT MAX(MMID) FROM Table1
            WHERE DateEntered >= '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000'
            GROUP BY GID, MID
        )
        intersect
    SELECT GID, MID FROM Table1 
        WHERE MMID IN (
            SELECT MIN(MMID) FROM Table1
            WHERE DateEntered < '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000'
            GROUP BY GID, MID
        )`? If non-zero, then `not exists` is working as designed.

Comment: Edited my question, I hope it wont be confusing anymore. My previous question is still not answered correctly. I commented on every answer to clarify further more things.

Comment: "So I intersect and get the values which are present before and after a date range. Then I remove it with Not exists." No you don't. The sub-query only asks if there are GID, MID pairs that exist before and after. If one is found, nothing will be returned by the outer query.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Yes, it gives 100 rows

Comment: And thus `not exists` is false.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance But outer query gives 200 results. So I am just trying to have non exits. So, how could i change this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your select statement behind the "not exists" phrase have some rows, your main select statement results in zero rows. 
The reason is, that you didn't have a connection between the main selection and the subselect after "not exists".
Maybe what you want is something like this:

```
Select * From Table1 as A 
WHERE (DateEntered >= '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000') 
AND Not exists (Select 1 From Table1 as B 
    where A.gid = B.gid and A.mid = B.mid
    And ... something else or your intersection
```

You have to connect the selection results.

Maybe a having clause is easier:

```
Select gid, mid from Table1
group by gid, mid
HAVING MIN(DateEntered) >= '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000';
```

In the having clause you check if the group (here: gid,mid) fulfill the having condition.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this does what you want?

```
SELECT GID, MID
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY GID, MID
HAVING MIN(DateEntered) >= '2015-06-13';
```

This is based on your explanation, not your query.

Comment: Thanks alot. I was looking at this only.

Answer (score 0):

Correlated sub-query, so the subquery references the values in the outer query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 OuterTable1
WHERE (DateEntered >= '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
    FROM Tabel1 InnerTable1
    WHERE InnerTable1.DateEntered < '2015-06-13 00:00:00.000'
    AND InnerTable1.GID = OuterTable1.GID
    AND InnerTable1.MID = OuterTable1.MID)
```